# Can't join LAN game in Civilization 6

Tags: networking, windows-10, java, gaming

Few days ago I was able to play Civilization VI through LAN (Offline on Steam) without any problems, but after Windows Update (installed 9/14/2019) I don't see any games in LAN.
On 9/14/2019 I also tried connecting Fiddler to my Java Application with following code:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");
```

Also I had some certificate problems so I tried to resolve problem with this code:

```
props.setProperty("jdk.internal.httpclient.disableHostnameVerification", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
System.setProperty("com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation", "false");
```

Things I tried to do to resolve problem:

- turn off Windows Firewall and Avast Antyvirus Firewall
- uninstall Windows Update from 9/14/2019
- clear system properties that I changed before

  ```
  System.clearProperty("http.proxyHost");
  System.clearProperty("http.proxyHost");
  System.clearProperty("http.proxyHost");
  System.clearProperty("http.proxyHost");
  ```